# Sending custom events to google analytics via local html inconsistency

Tags: google-analytics-4

I've implemented JavaScript code to send an event to Google Analytics from a local HTML file. It successfully works when I open the HTML file using Visual Studio Code's 'open with live server' option but doesn't work when I double-click and open the HTML file in a browser. What could be the reason for this inconsistency?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script async src="gtag.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'G-AAAA', { 'send_page_view': false });

        // Manually trigger an event
        gtag('event', 'my_event', {
            'user_id': 1
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt. Show your debugging attempts.

Comment: BNazaruk, 
Except for my key, I posted an example of the code.
The code works on the live server, but not when opened as an HTML file.

Comment: You're missing a large chunk of debugging. Show the DOM, show the Network tab, try to reproduce in the console, etc. It might turn out that you just have a trivial adblocker blocking the requests.

Comment: I don't have Adblocker (no extensions installed at all). In the network tab, there are only 2 objects: 1.test.html 2.js?G-XXXX which is my HTML and the gtag javascript. Can't paste the src here because it's too long but it's pretty much the same as in the original message, I just replaced <script async src="gtag.js"></script> with
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXX"></script>

Comment: open the console, open your network tab, make sure you're looking at ALL requests, clear the history, execute your gtag() command. Report what happens. This is very basic minimal reproducible example work you should be able to do after reading the SO article on it.

Comment: I'm looking at ALL requests and see only those 2 (when running with the live server I can see other resources, such as collect?v=...) but my question is when running the HTML directly without the live server. when executing gtag() from the console it prints undefined and nothing happens.

Comment: Just because the output is different from what you expected doesn't mean I don't know how to use the debugging tools. Thanks for trying to help anyway

Comment: ah, I think I see. You're loading gtag.js locally. it probably can't find it without the live server. Use the full path to the file there. Better yet, use the remote path to load it. downloading the script and loading it locally is not a good practice in case of gtag since it can change depending on user config.

Comment: Because they are in the same folder, it successfully found the file, but I also tried loading the script remotely from https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXX Unfortunately, it did not help, the behavior remained the same.